# How to reference a comment with links (with highlighting)?

Tags: feature-request

Referencing a comment on a question or answer is only possible by looking at the HTML code (anchors are produced for every comment). Is there a reason why there's no button which copies a link to the anchor of the question?

I guess some trouble might occur due to difficulties triggering the highlighting function which is used when opening a link to a status change from the notification panel as this link only refers to an HTML anchor and maybe sends further parameters for highlighting via POST (but I don't know about that). Providing the highlighting for links to comments would be nice though even for links which come from outside the SE node or even SE.

EDIT:
Example:
I got the following link for notification that a comment has been added to an answer I commented: ["Inner exception" (with traceback) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350671/inner-exception-with-traceback-in-python/13018468#comment35450304_13018468). If you open it the comment is highlighted. I want that link (with one click on a button next to the comment)! The button might look like this and be placed like in this edited screenshot of the page of the answer linked above:
[image: edited screenshot of proposed create comment link button]

Comment: Maybe it is me but after reading for the third I still have no clue what the problem is and what the feature request is. Can you maybe add a screenshot (with red free-hand circles of course)

Comment: @Karl did you mean this: [Improve the usability/intuitiveness of direct comment links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links)

Comment: You can just [right click on the timestamp of the comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/) to copy the link.

Comment: I thought about changing this feature request (which is a duplicate of @chuex 's link) into requesting my proposed copy button instead of the "edited X time units/date" link next to the comment because the idea of retrieval of the link connected with the date still seems very strange (I would have never thought about clicking on this link without wanting to see the revision history of the comment... - yes, I could have tried before posting or have RTFM). -> close as duplicate of a completed feature request

Answer (score 19):

Click on the date next to the comment, it links to the url you want.

Clicking on the link will set the url anchor to the comment, it also gets highlighted and scrolled into view. Then just copy that url from the address bar and share it.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it is rather not user friendly since clicking on timestamp does not suggest at all that you will get a permalink.